# Loader gif delay compared to browser's loader image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here's a code snippet I've got where I'm trying to show a 'loader' gif. I'm testing on my localhost and works fine. However with a little observation now I wonder is it really showing the gif while php pulls data from the SQL data base or otherwise.

My observation is, when I clear browser cache and refresh the page, I see the browser's loader images turns a couple of rounds before my page's loader loads. Am I missing something?

PS: The loader gif I've got is a very light file obviously.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
                $("#wait").css("display", "block");
            });
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
                $("#wait").css("display", "none");
            });
            $("#text").load("example.php");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Change Content</button>
    <div id="wait" style="display:none;"><img src="../images/loader.gif"></div>
    <div id="text"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Whenever testing loading images like that, I like to put an artificial delay in the script being called.  usleep(3000);  will give you a 3 second pause.  With the delay in there it lets you visually verify if your loader images are displaying like you hope on a slow connection.

Comment: @SymeonQuimby Thank you, that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great way to test loader images used in ajax calls while developing is to introduce an artificial delay in the script you are calling.

```
usleep(3000);
```

This will make the script sleep for 3 seconds, simulating a decent amount of network delay, allowing you to visually see your loader images in action.